# How do you authorize a C# web api call with curl?

Tags: c#, php, curl, asp.net-web-api

I have a standard C# web api using Forms authentication:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace API
{
    [Authorize]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public object Get(string tunnel)
        {

            return new
                {
                    test = "whatever"
                };
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to access it with a PHP curl request:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array();
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';

$auth_header = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $auth_header)); // doesn't work
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  //Also doesn't work
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// execute cURL
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've tried using the CURLOPT_USERPWD and header for Authorization basic as in the code above but neither work. They both come back with "Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."

Here is the full error message after adding CORS headers:

```
"HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["a26902e9-d6ef-4a7b-910f-be8a8cd99c85","4db4f730-97c9-4492-9b57-b97ab72f0b49","f524ee6f-c8a6-47aa-8db7-681f7f15c162"] X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2XHR1bm5lbGRhdGFcVHVubmVsRGF0YVxhcGlcU2FsZXNDb3N0Y29UZXN0?= X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 17:01:44 GMT Content-Length: 61 {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}"
```

How do you authenticate to the API?

Comment: If you convert the `user:pass` into `base64` string, does it contain any of these(`/` `+` `_` `-`) in it? What happens when you do the same from `c#` over the same user:pass? Are they same? Base64 has different implementation in different languages.

Comment: @SabujHassan, if you use UTF8 encoding in C# they come out the same.  I'm guessing that I have to do some other method entirely passing a token or something.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If you have an answer please update. Thanks

Comment: @Leandro don't think I ever solved it

Answer (score 0):

does the server api has Cross Domain allow?

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

try that.

Comment: See the update to the original post.  Adding headers doesn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: Hace you try checking if your PHP has any errors? that could trough a 500 error??? it happens some times.. you could try with a print some value and see if returns it not using C#..